# request an AlamoFire url using swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, alamofire

I just found this method writing way back I change `AlamoFire.request` to `AF.request` & `.responseSwiftyJSON { (dataResponse) in` to `.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (dataResponse) in` I did copy it but I'm trying to use it, I'm not familiar with alamoFire this is the first time I'm using it can anyone update this method for requesting a URL from AlamoFire 
I'm just facing these errors

1- isSuccess' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

2- Value of type 'Result' has no member 'value'

3- isFailure' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

4- Value of type 'Result' has no member 'error'

```
@objc func searchPlaces(query: String) {
        let urlStr = "\(MapBox.mapbox_api)\(query).json?access_token=\(MapBox.mapbox_access_token)"

        AF.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (dataResponse) in

            if dataResponse.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(dataResponse.result.value!)
                if let myjson = resJson["features"].array {
                    for itemobj in myjson ?? [] {
                        try? print(itemobj.rawData())
                        do {
                            let place = try self.decoder.decode(Feature.self, from: itemobj.rawData())
                            self.searchedPlaces.add(place)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } catch let error  {
                            if let error = error as? DecodingError {
                                print(error.errorDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if dataResponse.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = dataResponse.result.error!
            }

            })

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `isSuccess`(1), `isFailure`(3) you can actually switch on the `response.result`. For the `value`(2) from the response result, you can find it under `response.value` and last, but not least, the `error`(4) is available in the switch, check this sample code below that highlights all the relevant info to make your code work:

```
AF.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let resJSON = JSON(response.value)
                    ...
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            })
```